# Optional Ignore White Space in String (from Char set) Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
original_string = "(white || black) && (blue || yellow)"
```

And I replace each word with the text "replace" by doing:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', "replace", original_string)
```

So I get back:

```
"(replace || replace) && (replace || replace)"
```

This works fine. But I'd also like the same result even if the original_string included white spaces between the words (or even if it didn't).

For example:

```
original_string = (light pink || pink) && (very dark brown || blue)
```

I'd still like to get back:

```
"(replace || replace) && (replace || replace)"
```

I have seen other people ask this question, but when I try the solutions, I do not get the correct replacement (usually there is some issue with maintaining the parenthesis).  Some things I have already tried are:

```
 new_string = re.sub(r'[? \w+ ?]+', "replace", original_string)
 new_string = re.sub(r'[\w+( \w+)*$]+', "replace", original_string)
```

But neither of these give the desired results. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'\w[\w\t ]*\w|\w', "replace", original_string)
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so `[\w\t ]` will match word characters, tabs, and spaces.  So this regex means "match a word character, followed by any number of word characters or whitespace characters, followed by a word character, OR match a single word character".  This way you will match whitespace between words but not the whitespace before or after words.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation.

Comment: One follow up question - if I wanted to allow optional non alpha numeric characters to be a part of the string, like '$' or '-' or ',' how would I do that?  I just realized my original string might have things like: ($400,000-500 || blah) && (blah || blah)

Comment: You the following for your regex: `r'[\w$\-,][\w$\-,\t ]*[\w$\-,]|[\w$\-,]'`, the change here is to add each of those characters to a character class.  The `-` needs to be escaped otherwise it is interpreted as a range (like with `a-z` or `0-9`).

Comment: Ah ok, I was escaping all of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest to what you were trying that would work would be this:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'(\w *)+\w', "replace", original_string)
```

Comment: You can use `\w` inside of a character class.

Comment: @F.J Huh, I thought they were treated as literals for some reason... Thanks for pointing that out ^^